# C# replace string

Tags: c#, string, replace, return

I'm trying to run this code to replace a string but when I do it gives me a error saying

`Error  1 A local variable named 'typeval' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'typeval', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

**This is the code**

```
public static string Replace(string typeval)
{
    string newType = "";
    string typeval = "";

    if (typeval.Equals("User Service Request"))
    {
        newType = typeval.Replace("User Service Request", "incident");
    }
    else if (typeval.Equals("User Service Restoration"))
    {
        newType = typeval.Replace("User Service Restoration", "u_request");
    }

    return newType;
}
```

Comment: And this error message was not enough to give the hint that maybe you should try to rename one of the two `typeval`s?

Comment: give different name to the variable typeval. Error is that u have already used the variable with this name in the Parent. just change the name of this variable will solve ur problem

Comment: Its advised you search for errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already defined `typeval once`. You cannot declare it again.

Remove `string typeval == ""`

You should also set `typval.Replace` to `typval` and not `newType`. Otherwise you will always return an empty string.

Finally you don't need the `if` statements. You could easily simplify the function to look like this.

```
public static string Replace(string typeval)
{
    typeval = typeval.Replace("User Service Request", "incident");
    typeval = typeval.Replace("User Service Restoration", "u_request");

    return typeval;
}
```

Comment: doesnt look like its working if i send User Service Request or User Service Restoration i get a return of u_request

Comment: @Deanvd Did you try the full code I posted? You should remove `newType` and replace those with `typeval`, e.g. `typeval = typeval.Replace("User Service Request", "incident");` and then return `typeval`, not `newType`.

Comment: The code above executed with `Console.WriteLine(Replace("User Service Request 5 -- User Service Restoration 6"));` returns `incident 5 -- u_request 6`.

Comment: @eandersson    -   i tried 'code' your code exactly like below :(

public static string Replace(string typeval)
{
    typeval = typeval.Replace("User Service Request", "incident");
    typeval = typeval.Replace("User Service Restoration", "u_request");

    return typeval;
}

Comment: @eandersson i get the result desired(via visual studio) but now have to add it in to BizTalk as inline c# then i dont get it :(

Comment: Can you post an example output from BizTalk? The function def works fine, probably something else causing the issue.

Comment: @eandersson thank you so much for your help! it helped a lot i managed to do this with a BizTalk functoid

Comment: That is great @Deanvd. As DJ Burb mentioned earlier if this was the solution make sure to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two typevals.  One in the parameter and one inside the function.  Rename one of them

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring a local varaible with the same name as the Method Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables named 'typeval', hence the compilation error.